# Only getting the same udp packets

Tags: java, for-loop, datagram, packets

I'm a novice at java and I just created 2 programs that use UDP packets(Client and Server). The Client gets an integer from a user and sends that number to the Server. The Server then subtracts 2 from the integer and sends it back to the Client. The messages wil go back and forth until the Client receives a non-positive number from the Server. The problem is I keep receiving the same number. Does anyone know how to solve this? Do I need several loops?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client {

public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException{

            DatagramSocket ds = new DatagramSocket();

            System.out.println("Insert number: "); 
            Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
            int num = s.nextInt();

            int port = 1999;
            byte[] byteSend = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(num).array();
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
            byte[] byteReceive = new byte[4];
            DatagramPacket dpReceive = new DatagramPacket(byteReceive, byteReceive.length);

                DatagramPacket dpSend = new DatagramPacket(byteSend, byteSend.length, address, port);
                if(num <=0){
                    ds.close();
                }else{

                for(int i = 0; i<=num; i+= 2){
                    ds.send(dpSend);
                    ds.receive(dpReceive);
                    num = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteReceive).getInt();
                    System.out.println("number received: " + num);
                }
                }
                ds.close();
                }               

}
```

Server Class

```
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;public class Server {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    DatagramSocket dg = new DatagramSocket(1999);

    while(true) {
    System.out.println("Listening");

    byte[] byteReceive = new byte[4];
    DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(byteReceive, byteReceive.length);
    dg.receive(dp);
    int num = ByteBuffer.wrap(dp.getData()).getInt();

    InetAddress address = dp.getAddress();
    int port = dp.getPort();

    int numResult = num - 2;
    byte[] byteSend = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(numResult).array();
    DatagramPacket dpSend = new DatagramPacket(byteSend, byteSend.length, address, port);

    System.out.println("number received: " + num);
    System.out.println("number now decreased to: " + numResult);
    dg.send(dpSend);

      }
    }
}
```

The output of the Client comes up as follows when 6 is entered:

Insert number:

6
number received: 4

number received: 4

number received: 4

The output of the Server comes up as follows:

Listening

number received: 6

number now decreased to: 4

Listening

Comment: I wonder if it would be easier for someone to help if you'd add a sample of the output created by those classes

Answer (score 0):

The client keeps sending the same number. You never update `dpSend`.

Comment: Thanks for that solution. I updated the packet but now i'm getting this output on the Server:
Listening
number received: 6
number now decreased to: 4
Listening
number received: 4
number now decreased to: 2
Listening
number received: 6
number now decreased to: 4
Listening
number received: 2
number now decreased to: 0
Listening

and on the Client i'm getting:
Insert number:
6
number received: 4
number received: 2
On the client, I wanted to include 0 as well, as it's part of the loop, but on the Server it repeats the number 6.